# Объединение строк/столбцов в XML/JAVA

Tags: xml, java

Здравствуйте. Мне нужно описать шаблон таблицы, чтобы в последующем написать JAVA-приложение, которое будет заполнять её. В таблице есть простые части, а есть, где столбцы содержат подстолбцы, а строки подстроки. С простыми я разобрался, а вот со вторыми никак что-то... Пишу в eclipse. Нужно как-то объединить строки и столбцы.

Comment: Не понятно... в чём проблема? Проблема в самой таблице? Как XML связан со всем этим?

Comment: Дада, в ней самой. Я не знаю как в ней объединить эти строки и столбцы.. А на языке XML я, собственно,и пишу всю эту таблицу..

Comment: Вам следует почитать о Java технологии JSP.<br/> JSP (JavaServer Pages) — технология, позволяющая веб-разработчикам легко создавать содержимое, которое имеет как статические, так и динамические компоненты. По сути, страница JSP является текстовым документом, который содержит текст двух типов: статические исходные данные, которые могут быть оформлены в одном из текстовых форматов HTML, SVG, WML, или XML, и JSP элементы, которые конструируют динамическое содержимое. Источник - http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSP

Comment: Ой.. а речь о Swing или о web?

Answer (score 1):

Я считаю надо создаватиь жесткую xml с dtd. Касательно построения таблицы после разбора xml даже незнаю, можно создать в столбцах и строках линки на открытие вложенных строк и столбцов, тогда неважно веб или десктоп приложение, покатит и там и там. Открытие можно сделать на том же табе где и основная таблица, либо по средствам всплывающего визарда.

Answer (score 1):

думаю для того чтоб понять как описать шаблон таблицы нужно изучить теорию сначала:
гуглите 1нф 2нф 3нф (первая, вторая и третья нормальные формы)

таблица это фактически двумерный массив отображения данных. ваша проблема состоит в том как привести данные к такому виду. эта проблема уже решена до вас, - разберитесь как решают эту проблему при проэктировании БД